# AS3/Flash: Calling a function MouseEvent from a datagrid click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I'm calling a function by clicking a button:

```
searchBT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,searchXML);
function searchXML(Event:MouseEvent)
```

I want to call the same function from a datagrid.

Right now, when clicking on the datagrid several dynamic text fields are filled with the data of the clicked row.

I nead to perform the function (searchXML) at the same time. This and other calls result in errors:

```
fullList.dataGrid.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, clickGrid);
function clickGrid(e:ListEvent):void
{
   searchXML(Event);
   ...
}
```

Any idea?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `searchXML` method waits for argument of `MouseEvent` type. You can redefine this method like this:

```
function searchXML(Event:MouseEvent = null)
```

And call it simple:

```
function clickGrid(e:ListEvent):void
{
   searchXML();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Cherniv. Again :) Could this be used for other events, like: clickGrid(Event:ListEvent = null)?

Comment: @Sergio you always welcome! it can be used for every argument of every function! it is kind of initial/default value for undefined arguments.